# Calling MATLAB through Python but through Linux Command Terminal

Tags: python, linux, matlab, shell, scripting

I want to run a certain Python script that calls MATLAB through the Ubuntu 12.04 command terminal. The script has this line:

```
os.system("matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "ReadFates5mm;quit"")
```

but it returns a syntax error on the last portion with ReadFates.. and I don't know how to fix it.

I know there's a way using the matlab python bridge but I would have to convert my matlab file into a function.

Thanks!

Comment: `os.system('matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "ReadFates5mm;quit"')` ? OR escape the quotes properly.

Comment: Got it! What difference does it make to ' ' vs " " though?

Comment: Added the explanation as answer.

Comment: @alvarezcl **There is absolutely no difference between `"` and `'`**. The problem is that, to include a literal `"` inside a string delimited with `"` you should escape it with a backslash. E.g. `"Say \"something\""`. The same is true for `'`: `'Say \'something\''`. To avoid using the backslash you can use a different delimiter(e.g. if the string include `"` you use `'` as delimiter, and if the string contains `'` you use `"`). By the way: [`os.system` shouldn't be used](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system). Replace it with `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Actually, there is a slight difference between using `"` & `'` in some scripting languages. `'something'` is string literal in **many** of the languages. Any escape character within singly quoted string is taken as literally. Also `'$variable'` will not be expanded in bash. etc. I am not very sure about usage of `'` vs `"` in python. I just wanted to tell OP, that "absolutely no difference between `"` and `'`" is not a generic statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the string properly.

Try:

```
os.system('matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "ReadFates5mm;quit"')
OR
os.system("matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r 'ReadFates5mm;quit'")
```

Alternately, you can escape the nested double quotes.

```
os.system("matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r \"ReadFates5mm;quit\"")
```

---

Explanation:

In your code,

```
 os.system("matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "ReadFates5mm;quit"")
           1                                      1'                22'
```

The double quote started at marker `1` ends at the market `1'` & the quote started at `2` ends at `2'`.
Basically, you need to escape the `"` at `1'` & `2`, using `\"`.

Alternately, you can use other quote character, `'`.

---

For more details, search for "string quoting & escape characters".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats